# I installed MiKTeX but I can't compile the file

Tags: miktex, latex-base, miktex2.9, compilation-error, miktex-update

I installed MiKTeX but I can't compile the file. This file worked perfectly on another computer

> ```
> This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (MiKTeX 2.9.6840 64-bit)
> entering extended mode
> (abntex2ups.tex
> LaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 5
> ! Undefined control sequence.
> \UseTextAccent ...up \@firstofone \let \@curr@enc 
>                                                   \cf@encoding \@use@text@en...
> l.2 \usepackage
>                {etex}
> ?
> ```

Comment: you haven't really given enough information to allow anyone to help, but no document should have `\usepackage{etex}` these days (although that is not the cause of the error, tex has not yet read that line)

Comment: since the error is on line 2 of your document, you should be able to show a complete two-line test file that reproduces the error.

Comment: \documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper,english,french,hifenização,spanish,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}

Comment: OK thanks, I get same and I updated my answer.

Comment: the problem is actually the option `hifenização`

Comment: What does the option `hifenização` do? I could see no option of that name in the class code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option `hifenização` does not work with current latex, may need a change in latex and/or the class to fix that. But until it is fixed, you can use the form below:

```
\UseRawInputEncoding
\documentclass[12pt,openright,oneside,a4paper,english,french,hifenização,spanish,sumario=tradicional]{abntex2}
%\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```